# Network Unavailable - How to do it (as in Twitter)

Tags: android, networking

I need my application does not cause an exception and ends when the smartphone does not have internet access, I would put a Network Unavailable message, as well as the official Twitter app for android is, someone can show me an example? Thank you.

Comment: can you give us some your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a quick solution:

```
try {
   // your network request goes here
} catch (IOException e) {
   // there is a problem with the connection, show an alert dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Funily enough, if you kept reading SOF, this new question gives the answer : [Add boundary control for image downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693386/add-boundary-control-for-image-downloads)